# expected ‘;’ before numeric constant

Tags: c

When compiling the following program, I get the error `expected ‘;’ before numeric constant`
. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define GPIOBase 0x4002 2000

uint32_t * GPIO_type(char type);

int main(void)
{
    GPIO_type('G');

    return 0;
}

uint32_t * GPIO_type(char type)
{
    return (uint32_t *) GPIOBase;
}
```

Comment: use `gcc -E` to find and kill preprocessor errors.

Comment: up voting, came across this exact issue. But in my case it was so not obvious

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is:

`#define GPIOBase 0x4002 2000`

And where you use it:

`return (uint32_t *) GPIOBase;`

becomes:

`return (uint32_t *) 0x4002 2000;`

Which is a compiler error.  There's a stray `2000` lingering after your `0x4002`.  I suspect you want:

`#define GPIOBase 0x40022000`

Answer (score 4):

The Problem is this line:

```
#define GPIOBase 0x4002 2000
```

You are trying to define more than just a constant within the symbol `GPIOBase`. When the definition is applied, your function looks like this:

```
uint32_t * GPIO_type(char type)
{
    return (uint32_t *) 0x4002 2000;
}
```

Which is not valid C code.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the macro, you get

```
return (uint32_t *) 0x4002 2000;
```

which isn't correct code.

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't make sense.

Your compiler sees:

```
uint32_t * GPIO_type(char type)
{
    return (uint32_t *) 0x4002 2000;
}
```

which is illegal C syntax.